# Count number of occurrences of multiple criteria

Tags: r, statistics

The data set in the url

```
url <- paste0("https://10d9b011-755b-4b59-9f64-dbfb2ae95d87.filesusr.com/",
                  "ugd/0c24ab_a29a977ec1404b69bf7cc34fcc58b073.csv?",
                  "dn=Aus%20GP%20Lap%20Data.csv"
```

looks like this

```
Year    driverId    time    position   lap     seconds
```

Year = num (1996-2019)

driverId = names of drivers (chr)

position = num (1-22)

lap = num (1-58)

I want to count how often (rel. freq) the same driverId has position 1 in both lap 1 and lap 58, basically how often does the driver who leads from the start win the race.

Does anyone know a good way to do this? I assume dplyr/tidyr is of good use here, I just don't have much experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you wanted. If not, please let me know.

Total `Year`'s are `24`.(`length(unique(df$Year))`)

Then, count the `Year` that fits your condition is,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(lap %in% c(1, 58), position == 1) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  filter(n() == 2, length(unique(driverId)) == 1) %>%
  select(Year, driverId) %>%
  distinct()

    Year driverId          
   <int> <chr>             
 1  1998 hakkinen          
 2  2001 michael_schumacher
 3  2004 michael_schumacher
 4  2007 raikkonen         
 5  2008 hamilton          
 6  2009 button            
 7  2011 vettel            
 8  2012 button            
 9  2015 hamilton          
10  2019 bottas
```

You can get count by `n_distinct`,

```
df %>%
  filter(lap %in% c(1, 58), position == 1) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  filter(n() == 2, length(unique(driverId)) == 1) %>%
  select(Year, driverId) %>%
  n_distinct()
[1] 10
```

Then `rel.freq` is `5/12`

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Much appreciated. If I now wanted to compare the starting positions and finishing positions for all driverId's by the correlation  between them perhaps, what's the easiest way of doing it? I know what I have to do, so to speak, just not really the code or the appropriate (tidyverse) functions for it without making it too messy or caveman like.

Comment: @Manbearpig Do you mean for each 113 unique `driverId`, get correlation coefficients? That have 113 correlations.

Comment: Sorry, poorly asked question.  To put it simply, I'm trying to investigate how much positions in general change from start to finish, and please let me know if there is a better (or easier) way of investigating how different (or similar) the order of the starting grid is to the finish result. If there is no "relatively" simple way of doing this analysis then so be it, I'll find something else to do :)

Comment: @Manbearpig I take a look at each `lap`, but there sometime doesn't exist at `lap 58`. If you ask some other question, I'll make sure to look up to your question :D.

Comment: Yeah, I see that as well now. Looking at it now, it seems those that finished more than 1 lap behind don't record a lap 58 as the race finishes after everyone crosses the finishing line after the chequered flag has been waved. And some years there have been accidents that prematurely ended the race before 58 laps, all of which makes the analysis too complicated for now.  

I am mathematically familiar with lm's and glm's (and to a small extent in R) and would like to try to fit a model to the data, and I am open to suggestions as to what to try to model and which models to try.

Comment: @Manbearpig As I understand your goal is that to focus on change of position from `lap 1` and `lap 58`, and some are gone somewhere before `lap 58`, so they do not exist at `lap 58`.  Then, it's just my thought, and might be silly. How about get ratio of those who are **gone** before the final lap. Then suppose that for in every year's race are independent, simply look at correlation of position at first and last lap, or fit a regression for `position_at_lap58 ~ driver_id + position_at_lap1`. I'm not sure which regression model will fit that.(not might be linear or do not know about link ftn.)